# Intercept Javascript requests with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a Chrome extension that intercepts some data that a Javascript-based application is requesting. The URLs it requests its data from constantly change, so I can't just guess what they'll be. If I watch the Developer Console in Chrome, I can see all the requests I want. Is there a way to get an extension to automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this example extension from Google: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/samples.html#cc8563a6666add797264184a960c7b7c8bd3e64d

"Displays the live log with the http requests headers"

Comment: This documentation should also help: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html

Comment: Links are a terrible way to answer questions. For example, these links are both are now 404s.